# Mark points on contour line using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour, edge-detection

I want to make set of points in similar distance on a edge line of plant leaf (as shown in the below image). I want to make the red coloured small square on the edge line of the leaf.I store the set of points of the leaf edge line as contour.

[image]

Is there any way to do this using OpenCV/C++ ? (specially I want a way to store those points for future use of the application)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate  [approxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp) for the contour you already found, the approxPolyDP approximates a polygonal curves with the specified precision, where you can adjust the parameter **epsilon** to get desired result.

See an [example](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) here for how to use  approxPolyDP.

Answer (score 2):

1. FindContours to extract the contours of your image. (convert your image to grayscale, apply binary threshold and canny edge detection before, for better results.)

   vector> contours;
   cv::findContours( src_img, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
2. Draw all the points of contour. Code example:

   cv::Mat draw = cv::Mat::zeros( 500,500, CV_8UC3 );

   int contour_id = 1;

   for(int i = 0; i< contour[contour_id].size(); i++)
   {
       cout << contour[contour_id][i] << endl;
       cv::circle(draw,contour[contour_id][i],1,cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
   }

Beside that you can also use [ApproxPolyDP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contours#approxpolydp) or PointPolygonTest Opencv functions for all points on contour. See complete detail and code example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#point-polygon-test). As you can read on link this function returns the distance which is negative when point is outside the contour, positive when point is inside and zero if point is on the contour.
So you have to draw only points which return zero.

Regards